# In Coffeescript, can I call the constructor for an object after it has already been created?

Tags: coffeescript

In Coffeescript, can I call the constructor for an object after it has already been created? Like this:

```
class Snake
  constructor: (@name) ->

obj = new Snake()
// do stuff
obj.constructor("Python")
```

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: To be fair, it is somewhat of a hack to avoid having to modify/refactor the constructor call in dependent code. "//do stuff" sets up variables that are normally set by Snake's subclass.

Comment: Yes you can do this no problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. CoffeeScript class syntax is just syntax sugar for JavaScript constructor functions, which are just normal functions that you can call:

```
class Example
  count: 0
  constructor: (@name) -> 
    @count += 1

e = new Example 'foo'
console.log e.count # -> 1
console.log e.name  # -> foo

# Call contructor again over the same instance:
Example.call e, 'bar'
console.log e.count # -> 2
console.log e.name  # -> bar

# If you don't have the constructor in a variable:
e.constructor.call e, 'baz'
console.log e.count # -> 3
console.log e.name  # -> baz
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is compiled to:

```
var Snake, obj;

Snake = (function() {
  function Snake(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  return Snake;
})();

obj = new Snake();
```

So there is no `constructor()` method, coffeescript is just using it to generate the `Snake()` function.

So no you can't. But why would you want to do that if your code is object oriented?